# Python program that tells you whether or not you need an umbrella when you leave the house

Tags: python, function, python-requests, pycharm, python-module

The program should:

1. Ask you if it is raining using input()
2. If the input is 'y', it should output 'Take an umbrella'
3. If the input is 'n', it should output 'You don't need an umbrella'

Comment: This is very basic, you should really try doing it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this in several ways:

```
if input('it is raining now? y/n ') == 'y':
    print('Take an umbrella')
else:
    print("You don't need an umbrella")
```

also you can do it in just one line like this which is probabely an advanced way:

```
print('Take an umbrella' if (input('it is raining now? y/n: ') == 'y') else "You don't need an umbrella")
```

also you can first save the input in a variable, and then handle it in *if* blocks

```
x = input('it is raining now? y/n ')
if x.lower() == 'y':
    print('Take an umbrella')
elif x.lower() == 'n':
    print("You don't need an umbrella")
else:
    print('wrong input')
```

the *x.lower()* makes it acceptable even if user inputs Y or N in capital letters.

Comment: please do not forget to mark this answer as approved answer :)